# Questions regarding JWT

Tags: node.js, express, security, jwt, backend

so i currently try to setup "remember me" functionality with nodejs jwt cookies.
[Here](https://jwt.io/) i found a example for a encrypted cookie. I also read their introduction. Now i plan using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) middleware for express to store the user_id for identification with a mysql database.
My questions to that are:

- On the jwt site there is a debugger when i change the secret only the signature changes wouldn't be that more secure if the payload was encrypted using the secret?
- How many characters should the secret have to be not bruteforcable 512, 1024 2048?
- How fast is the secret bruteforceble? How often should it be changed if brute-forcing is fast?
- What is the best practise to secure the token with the module mentioned above? Also how to set the token (the usage example shows only how to read)?

My main concern is currently that when someone could craft a token he could set his user_id and have access to any account. I would love if someone could clarify that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: On the jwt site there is a debugger when i change the secret only the signature changes wouldn't be that more secure if the payload was encrypted using the secret?

The main requirement for JWTs is that it is digitally signed.  If you put sensitive data in the JWT then you would also need to encrypt it.  But I strongly recommend that you do not put sensitive data in there because if a user loses his JWT token, then you would want to minimise the damage.  For example, in the [OWASP juice shop](https://juice-shop.herokuapp.com/) web application (deliberately insecure web application for the purpose of teaching people security) they put the user's password hash in the token/.  This allows an attacker to recover the user password via cross site scripting as demo'ed in [this blog](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2018/06/24/demonstrating-reflected-versus-dom-based-xss/).

Q:    How many characters should the secret have to be not bruteforcable 512, 1024 2048?

Depends upon the JWT algorithm you are using.  If you are using HMAC, then 256-bits (32 bytes) is plenty, much more than you need.  If you are using RSA, then 2048-bit (256-bytes) is best practice.

Q:    How fast is the secret bruteforceble? How often should it be changed if brute-forcing is fast?

It is not brute forceable in the lifetime of the Universe using all computers on the planet, assuming quantum computers do not become a reality (if quantum computers do become a reality, then all bets are off).  Cryptographers are very smart people and they design these algorithms in this way.  For example, if you want to learn about RSA security, start by looking into the [general number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) and the running time for attacking it. :-)  This is not brute force -- brute force is a slow, dumb attack -- but instead it is an intelligent algorithm based upon algebraic properties of the modulus.

So, in summary, use recommended key size for the algorithm you choose, and don't worry about rotating the key unless you have reason to believe it is compromised.  If only one place needs to verify the token and that place is the same as the one that generates the token, then HMAC is a fine choice.  However, otherwise you would be better off with a public key algorithm like RSA.

Q:    What is the best practise to secure the token with the module mentioned above? Also how to set the token (the usage example shows only how to read)?

Since you are putting it in a cookie, follow the normal best practices for cookies (Secure, HttpOnly, etc...).